# C pre-processor macros

Tags: c, macros

I have a question about macros in C programming. What I know about macros is that they are pre-processor directives and are done before the compile stage and they are deleted. So I've written a piece of code to test this but it still works after the compile stage:

```
#define SWAP(x,y) {int temp; temp = *x;*x = *y;*y=temp;}

int main()
{
      int data1, data2;
      while((scanf("%d%d",&data1,&data2)) == 2)
      {
          SWAP(&data1,&data2);
          printf("Data1 =%d, data2 = %d\n",data1,data2);
      }
}
```

I have no idea why this piece of code still works.

Comment: What do you mean by *it still works after the compile stage*?

Answer (score 1):

Because the macro did what it was supposed to do.
The preprocessor took the line

```
SWAP(&data1,&data2);
```

and replaced it with

```
{int temp; temp = *data1;*data1 = *data2;*data2=temp;};
```

Then feed that to the compiler, which did it's job, and your program works.

Macros are TEXTUAL replacement that happens before compilation.

Comment: Thank you very much this explains alot :)

Answer (score 0):

The macros are not delete after the compile time. When the processor run (step before compilation) it find all the occurrences of SWAP and replace with their definition, at such times all the code is expanded and compiled without throubles.